# How to add Intellisense in my IDE

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, intellisense

I have made an online IDE in MEAN stack and it writes code and gives result from the server, to make it better I want to provide intellisense like feature in VSCode or Atom to my IDE. How can I do that? Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Depends on which programming languages your IDE supports. Also, Intellisense is a trademark of Microsoft. I doubt you will get a good answer here, so let's study the topic a bit more to have a narrower question.

Comment: So, does microsoft or any other provides any api to implement Intellisense like feature in my IDE?

Comment: VS Code is fully open-source, it is implemented in TypeScript, but they leave it to the language plugins to provide warnings, errors and quick fixes. If you implement an interface similar to VS Code for its language plugins, you  might be able to reuse some of those efforts. It will be more work than writing your own language extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out LSP protocol spec : https://github.com/Microsoft/language-server-protocol and server implementation : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node which VS code is using for their language service.